# How to connect to a MongoDB over SSH from Debezium

Tags: mongodb, ssh, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I want to connect to a MongoDB instance over ssh in my Debezium.

Connection to MongoDB doesn't have a ssh required, and it is going through, but with SSH I am receiving a time out exception.

I am using regular kafka-connect properties as mentioned below.

```
name=XYZ 
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector 
tasks.max=1 
database.list=XXXXXX:27017 
connection.url=xxxx:27017 
mongodb.hosts=xxxx:27017 
mongodb.name=xyz 
collection.whitelist=xyz.collection1 
database.whitelist=xyz 
converter.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter 
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter 
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter 
key.converter.schemas.enable=false 
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

Comment: Can you share the configuration that you're using please?

Comment: I am using regular kafka-connect properties as mentioned below.

name=XYZ
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector
tasks.max=1
database.list=XXXXXX:27017
connection.url=xxxx:27017
mongodb.hosts=xxxx:27017
mongodb.name=xyz
collection.whitelist=xyz.collection1
database.whitelist=xyz
converter.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

Comment: Can the machine running Kafka Connect establish an SSH connection to the machine running MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you mean SSL, not SSH...

The documentation for setting up TLS for Mongo is [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/), and I'm not immeadiately sure how Debezium handles that, but I do see the `mongodb.ssl.enabled` property on the Debezium docs

---

If you did literally mean SSH, then you might be able to setup an SSH *tunnel*, to your database<sup>1</sup>, but this would be **external** to Kafka Connect process, and you would connect to `127.0.0.1:(tunnel_port)`

Copied from - [how to connect to mongodb server via ssh tunnel](https://serverfault.com/questions/597765/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-server-via-ssh-tunnel)

Establish the tunnel on **each** connect worker.

```
ssh -fN -l root -i path/to/id_rsa -L 9999:localhost:27017 mongo-host.com
```

Then update your Connect config to use `127.0.0.1:9999`

<sup>1</sup>*Disclaimer* : Not tested